# How do I store two eloquent models from one form?

Tags: php, forms, eloquent

Okay I am taking a php class right now and we had to create two eloquent objects (orders and items) and make a form where the user would place the order using those two eloquent objects.  So I currently have one form, two eloquent objects, two controllers each with a store() method for their own eloquent object.  And currently both controllers make the view page.  Do I need to create another controller to store both of them or is there a way to route to the separate controller pages.

Here is the form currently:

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
<p class="'error">{{ $error }}</p>
@endforeach

{{ Form::open() }}

<input type="number" name="part_number" placeholder="Part Number" />
<input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
<input type="number" name="annual_usage" placeholder="Annual Usage" />
<input type="submit" value="Add Item" />
```

(This is where the item eloquent object is added)

```
<input type="textarea" name="comment" placeholder="Comment" />
<input type="text" name="shippingaddress" placeholder="Shipping Address" />
<input type="text" name="project_id" placeholder="Project Id" />
<input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="User Id" />
<input type="submit" value="Send Orders" />
{{ Form::close() }}
```

(This is where the order eloquent object is added)

Comment: It's not controller's job to persist anything to the storage. Controller should process request and send response. That being said, I'd suggest creating another layer (repositories are trendy nowadays ;) ) that will take care of saving your models (separately, together or whatever your business needs are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with deczo the easiest way to do this is a repository and feeding them through the view but unfortunately I just do not think you are at the level to code this.  Your teacher obviously hasn't explained repositories or relationships.